# Field calculator 'if/then' statement, with 'and' not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, if-statement

I'm trying to do some conditional formatting of an attribute table using Field Calculator. I tried using code below, but am not getting any returns that meet conditions specified (even though the conditions exist). What am I doing wrong? I am new to coding, so please assume I am ignorant to obvious mistakes.

My steps so far:

1. Created a new field "Raster_code" (this is the field where I am using field calculator)
2. Open field calculator, set parser to Python, enter the following pre-logic script:

```
def ifBlock(BGCLMTCLBL,STSRSLBLC1):
    if 'BGCLMTCLBL' == 'AT' and 'STSRSLBLC1' == '00':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Note: "BGCLMTCLBL" and "STSRSLBLC1" are two separate fields. I want to locate records containing a certain combination of values from these respective fields

3. Enter the following in the Raster_code block:

```
ifBlock(!BGCLMTCLBL!,!STSRSLBLC1!)
```

The result I get is 0 for all records-- in other words, the conditions were not met.

Here is a screenshot of the above-noted fields in my attribute table.
[image: screenshot of attribute table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes around the field names on second row:

```
def ifBlock(BGCLMTCLBL,STSRSLBLC1):
    if BGCLMTCLBL == 'AT' and STSRSLBLC1 == '00':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

If not you are asking python if the string 'BGCLMTCLBL' is the same as 'AT' which it isnt. BGCLMTCLBL without quotes is the variable holding your field values.

Comment: Note that ALLCAPS variable names are not best practice in Python.